# Fields removed after update() $set?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

As an example, my users collection looks as so:

```
_id: MhReTBKqXR9xTGuK4,
profile: {
    name: 'Nathan',
    wins: '16',
    team: 'The Mashers'
}
```

So, let's say I want to change the name of my team:

```
Meteor.users.update({...},{ $set: { profile: { team: 'The Bashers' } } });
```

I'm assuming my team name has been updated, while the rest of my fields have not changed. But, when I call to find my user I get this:

```
_id: MhReTBKqXR9xTGuK4,
profile: {
    team: 'The Bashers'
}
```

The fields that I did not update are now gone! Where did they go? I don't understand why those fields were deleted. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Yes, you update profile with new value wich equels { team: 'The Bashers' }, but you can try to do { $set: { profile.team: 'The Bashers' } }

Comment: When I do this I get an error:

`Unexpected token .`

Comment: Are you get profile.team in quotes?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
Meteor.users.update({...},{ $set: { 'profile.team': 'The Bashers' } });
```